# Ubuntu and Backups

Tags: nas

So this is a little strange. I have a NAS that supports NDMP backups but it uses a proprietary file system. It does however support snapshots. I want to setup an Ubuntu server to backup these snapshots. The NAS is looking for a DMA. What software do i need on my Ubuntu box for this?

Comment: Posting the model of your NAS could help us a little more. Also to know what proprietary file system that is.

Comment: It is at another site and not networked at the moment. I can get that info later but I guess in general I am just trying to find out if I can  make my Ubuntu server a NDMP backup server that is discoverable from systems that support that protocol.